# Authzforce condition evaluation of matchAny in multi-valued string

Tags: authzforce

I'm looking for a way to define a condition in a policy rule, so that when we pass a multiple string value in our certificate  and try to authenticate authzforce against that rule, assuming the string value in the condition is equal to one of the string values we passed in the certificate, I want the rule to evaluate to 'true'.
For example if the attribute value of the condition is "DNS:google.com" and the multiple value string we receive from the certificate are: ["DNS:google.nl" ,"DNS:google.com"], I would expect to get the rule evaluated to 'true' as one of those values are equal to the value of the condition ("DNS:google.com").

I tried to achieve this defining a rule with this condition:

```xml
<Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-is-in">
  <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">DNS:google.com</AttributeValue>
  <AttributeDesignator Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:certificate" AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:certificate-category:subject-alternative-name" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
</Apply>
```

I used the 'string-is-in' XACML operator in the condition, however the rule evaluates to false.
The attributes I send via the certificate using the crypto library look like this when they reach the PDP:

```xml
  <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:certificate">
    <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:certificate-category:subject-alternative-name" IncludeInResult="false">
      <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">DNS:google.com</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
  </Attributes>
  <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:certificate">
    <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:certificate-category:subject-alternative-name" IncludeInResult="false">
      <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"> DNS:google.nl</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
  </Attributes>
```

Right now, the way I defined the condition rule and the the way I sent the multi-string in the certificate, I manage to get the rulet to evaluate to 'true' only if ALL values of the certificate are equal or contain the string value of the condition as a substring. So its more of a "matchAll". That is not what I want - I would like the rule to be evaluated to 'true' if we even have one string on the multi-string in the certificate equal to the string in the condition - meaning a an i'm looking to implement a "matchAny" approach rather than the "matchAll" approach I have here.

Could you please advise me why the rule evaluates to 'false' with my current implementation and how to correct it, using perhaps a different XACML operator?
Pasting the policy below as well as in the comments.

```xml
<PolicySet PolicySetId="root" Version="0.1.2" PolicyCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:policy-combining-algorithm:deny-unless-permit"
    xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17">
    <Target/>
    <Policy PolicyId="dbfcb643-cb39-4560-9c11-95112df970d0" Version="0.1.0" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:rule-combining-algorithm:deny-unless-permit" MaxDelegationDepth="10">
        <Description>Policy for EAP authentications by SAN dns domains</Description>
        <Target/>
        <Rule RuleId="86ef9adb-2acb-43a1-aac6-b01fdeab9a44" Effect="Permit">
            <Description>Permit by certificate's SAN dns domain</Description>
            <Condition>
                <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:and">
                    <Description>new condition</Description>
                    <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:function:any-of">
                        <Function FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal"/>
                        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">EAP</AttributeValue>
                        <AttributeDesignator Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:environment" AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:environment:radius-auth-type" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
                    </Apply>
                    <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-is-in">
                        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">DNS:google.com</AttributeValue>
                        <AttributeDesignator Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:certificate" AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:certificate-category:subject-alternative-name" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
                    </Apply>
                </Apply>
            </Condition>
            <AdviceExpressions>
                <AdviceExpression AdviceId="authorization-result" AppliesTo="Permit">
                    <AttributeAssignmentExpression AttributeId="profile-id">
                        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">bbfc5e21-0e9f-40a6-a5c6-fedd921bff2c</AttributeValue>
                    </AttributeAssignmentExpression>
                </AdviceExpression>
            </AdviceExpressions>
        </Rule>
    </Policy>
```

Comment: You can do this in a Target/Match. Please show the XACML policy, it will be easier to tell what's wrong.

Comment: <Policy PolicyId="dbfcb643-cb39-4560-9c11-95112df970d0" Version="0.1.0" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:rule-combining-algorithm:deny-unless-permit" MaxDelegationDepth="10">
        <Description>Policy for EAP authentications by SAN dns domains</Description>
        <Target/>
        <Rule RuleId="86ef9adb-2acb-43a1-aac6-b01fdeab9a44" Effect="Permit">
            <Description>Permit by certificate's SAN dns domain</Description>
            <Condition>
            ...  //content of condition in the next comment
          </Condition>

Comment: <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:and">

<Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-is-in">
                        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">DNS:google.com</AttributeValue>
                        <AttributeDesignator Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:certificate" AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:certificate-category:subject-alternative-name" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
                    </Apply>
                </Apply>

Comment: Right after the condition I have:
<AdviceExpressions>
                <AdviceExpression AdviceId="authorization-result" AppliesTo="Permit">
                    <AttributeAssignmentExpression AttributeId="profile-id">
                        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">bbfc5e21-0e9f-40a6-a5c6-fedd921bff2c</AttributeValue>
                    </AttributeAssignmentExpression>
                </AdviceExpression>
            </AdviceExpressions>
        </Rule>
    </Policy>

Comment: when I edited your question, I found out there was some XACML already but was hidden because formatting was wrong. now fixed

Comment: I'm confused because the <Condition> in the comment is not valid : you have an Apply "and" with only one argument (the string-is-in Apply), there should be a second argument. Are you sure you cannot put the full <Rule> (uncut) in the question?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this Cyril, I pasted the entire rule and policy as code in the original post. I do have an apply with a single argument which is the string I want one of the strings in the the multi-valued string I send in the certificate to match against. so for example in the condition rule as you can see I have this string:
"DNS:google.com" with the  xacml "string-is-in" func ID. Then I apply it against this multi-string input which I embed in the certificate (in the form of attributes):

(next 2 comment - had to break it to two chunks as per max comment length)

Comment: `<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:certificate">
  <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:certificate-category:subject-alternative-name" IncludeInResult="false">
   <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">DNS:google.com</AttributeValue>
  </Attribute>
 </Attributes>`

Comment: `<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:certificate">
  <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:certificate-category:subject-alternative-name" IncludeInResult="false">
   <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"> DNS:google.nl</AttributeValue>
  </Attribute>
 </Attributes>`

Comment: So what i'm trying to do is to evaluate those string attributes you see in the above two comments: DNS:google.com, DNS:google.nl against the condition in the rule I defined: DNS:google.com using the xcaml "string-is-in". What I was hoping to get is 'true' as one of those string attributes - DNS:google.com is equals to the string in the condition. So in other words i'm trying to achieve a match-any behavior where for a given SAN (subject alternative name) that looks like: "DNS:google.com", "DNS:google.nl" (multi-string), I can match only a portion of it. In this case "DNS:google.com"(condition)

Comment: I tried to use the xcaml function: string-contains and the result is a as matchAll rather then matchAny: when my condition is "DNS:google.com" and my attributes in policy are "DNS:google.com", "DNS:google.nl", I get 'false' for the policy evaluation. However when in the multi-string of the  SAN I give:"DNS:google.com","DNS:google.com" the rule evaluates to 'true'

Comment: Could you show the full <Request>? The attribute radius-auth-type must be present as well to have Condition true, don't see it.

Answer (score 1):

I found the bug, it was in the way build our request, originally our request was structured it like:

```xml
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:certificate">
  <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:certificate-category:subject-alternative-name" IncludeInResult="false">
    <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">DNS:google.com</AttributeValue>
  </Attribute>
</Attributes>
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:certificate">
  <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:certificate-category:subject-alternative-name" IncludeInResult="false">
    <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"> DNS:google.nl</AttributeValue>
  </Attribute>
</Attributes>`
```

The way it should be is like:

```xml
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:certificate">
  <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:certificate-category:subject-alternative-name" IncludeInResult="false">
    <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">DNS:google.com</AttributeValue>
  </Attribute>
  <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:certificate-category:subject-alternative-name" IncludeInResult="false">
    <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"> DNS:google.nl</AttributeValue>
  </Attribute>
</Attributes>
```

Meaning the  are nesting all the attributes within them rather than wrapping each attribute separately. When I structure the request as the latter the policy evaluation returns 'Permit'.

Comment: Also put all the <AttributeValue>s together in the same <Attribute> element (the AttributeId/Category is the same), and remove the whitespace before 'DNS:google.nl' as the strings are taken literally by the PDP. Else you may have other issues later.